# Restarting nginx nginx [fail]

Tags: nginx, vagrant, laravel-5

when I tried to run that on Vagrant:

```
serve damcapp /home/vagrant/Projects/dmca-app
```

I got this error:

```
dos2unix: converting file /vagrant/scripts/serve.sh to Unix format ...
 * Restarting nginx nginx        [fail] 
php5-fpm stop/waiting
php5-fpm start/running, process 3846
```

I've been read a lot about it and I checked that:

```
sudo nginx -t
```

and I got:

```
nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "listen" directive in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/damcapp:2
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

I was trying with port 80 in this file:

```
server {
    listen 80(**I added here**);
    server_name damcapp;
    root "/home/vagrant/Projects/dmca-app";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/damcapp-error.log error;

    sendfile off;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
     }

     location ~ /\.ht {
       deny all;
     }
}
```

Also, I notice that the route of this file is /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/**damcapp**(**notice the final name is different of my app dmca-app, I am not sure if it is correct. If it is not how can I change it?**).
After to update try serve command again and nginx fail again. Even I tried similar to the Laravel 5 documentation

```
serve damcapp /home/vagrant/Projects/dmca-app 80
```

adding 80 at the final and I got nothing. If I try to see /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/damcapp once again 80 number has dissapeared.
Finally I tried editing my ~/.homestead/aliases file adding 80 in this line:

```
sudo bash /vagrant/scripts/serve.sh "$1" "$2" 80
```

and nothing. I've been working with homestead provision when I needed a new site but that delete data created before. I am little bit frustrated.
Any suggestion please.
Kind Regards.

Comment: I've just edit the post and I put all config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that I solved my problem was with:
**homestead destroy and homestead up...** I am trying with serve command once again and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You might not have had an instance of Nginx running in the first place